# #3502 Object at URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the following error when I'm submitting a read action to Facebook -

> (#3502) Object at URL gettysburg_address has og:type of 'website'. The
>   property 'article' requires an object of og:type
>   'outside_limits:article'.

Where read is the action, gettysburg_address is the object, and article is the object type.

If I run the url through Facebook's object debugger, there are no errors. Facebook's response shows the og:type paramater is outside_limits:article. So, I don't understand why Facebook is sending my application an error if it believes I have the og:type specified correctly.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has started working without a code change. I do not know why.

Comment: There's a bug report about this,short version is that the debug tool is validating against the actions/object syntax in the new APIs, but Like buttons, etc will still work with the object types announced in 2010 and visible at http://ogp.me/